# Solution to the Laplace's equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am on my way to solve the hydrogen-atom in 3D, and now I am stucked with the Laplace's equation, where there occurs a "=", which I can't understand. 
[image]

Comment: Can you give some more information. What is $\theta$ and $f(0)$ and $l$ and $m$?

Comment: $θ$ is the angle in polar coordinates and $l$ and $m$ is some quantum numbers. Site 335: https://faculty.washington.edu/seattle/physics227/reading/reading-26-27.pdf

Comment: Looks like a mix of operators and functions in the first formula that has been converted only to usual derivatives and functions in second formula. But it's just a guess.

Answer (score 1):

You really have
$$
          \frac{d}{d\theta}\sin\theta\frac{d}{d\theta}
$$
No parentheses are needed when thinking of this in terms of operators. In the context of operators, you first differentiated in $\theta$ (operator on the far right,) and then multiply that result by $\sin\theta$, and then differentiate (operator on the far letft) the new product with respect to $\theta$. In other words,
\begin{align}
          \frac{d}{d\theta}\sin\theta\frac{d}{d\theta} f & = \frac{d}{d\theta}\left(\sin\theta\frac{df}{d\theta}\right) \\
      & =\cos\theta\frac{df}{d\theta}+\sin\theta\frac{d^2f}{d\theta^2},
\end{align}
which may be written in operator language as
$$
         \frac{d}{d\theta}\sin\theta\frac{d}{d\theta}= \cos\theta\frac{d}{d\theta}+\sin\theta\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}.
$$